# Modal not responsive to parent state change

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a modal which intakes data and displays some of this data on a modal where a user can interact with it. The data is set and the modal is opened through my `Starters` component via the `handleAdd` function. The modal then consumes the `homeData`, set within the `handleAdd` function. However, upon opening the modal, I see original data from `homeData`'s original state and I do not see the new `homeData` state set by `setHomeData` in the `handleAdd` function. This is odd because my modal does in fact tell me that `homeData` is the data that `handleAdd`/`setHomeData` sets it to when logging this in the modal.

Why is the original data being displayed on the modal instead of new data that I pass into it? How do I fix this?

Here's the code:

`Starters`, the code that handles the `setHomeData` call in `handleAdd`

```
  const Starters = ({item}) => {
    const handleAdd = (data) => {
      setHomeData(data);
      showHomeModal()
    };

    const data = {
      Name: item.title,
      Stack: item.stack,
      ScheduleName: item.subtitle,
      Track: true,
      TrackString: "true",
    }

    return (
      <Card
        style={{
          marginRight: 10,
          marginBottom: 6
        }}
      >
        <Card.Title
          title={item.title}
          subtitle={`Schedule: ${item.subtitle}`}
          right={() =>
            <IconButton
              icon="plus-circle"
              color="#5F9DA5"
              onPress={() => handleAdd(data)}
            />
          }
          rightStyle={{
            marginBottom: 22
          }}
        />
        // rest of card stuff...
  }
```

In my `HomeScreen` I have `Starters` being rendered like so:

```
const HomeScreen = () => {
  // some default data
  const [homeData,setHomeData] = useState({
    "ScheduleName": "Everyday",
    "Stack": [
      {
        "amount": "3900",
        "measure": "mg",
        "substance": "Omega3",
        id: "7846365hjbvbert674t"
      },
      {
        "amount": "25",
        "measure": "mg",
        "substance": "B12",
        id: "8r76438hjvfguy"
      },
      {
        "amount": "2",
        "measure": "Tablets",
        "substance": "B-complex",
        id: "783657345634hgvbhjvh"
      },
    ],
    "Name": "Example",
    "Track": false,
    "TrackString": "false",
    "StartDate": new Date().toISOString()
  });
  // data that handleAdd should be setting for the modal
  const itemData = {  
    "Vits": {
      title: "Morning Essentials",
      subtitle: "Everyday",
      stack: [
        {
          substance: "Omega3",
          amount: "3900",
          measure: "mg",
          id: uuidv4()
        },
        {
          substance: "B12",
          amount: "25",
          measure: "mg",
          id: uuidv4()
        },
        {
          substance: "B-complex",
          amount: "2",
          measure: "Tablets",
          id: uuidv4()
        }
      ]
    },
    "Vits2": {
      title: "Evening Essentials",
      subtitle: "Everyday",
      stack: [
        {
          substance: "Vitamin C",
          amount: "500",
          measure: "mg",
          id: uuidv4()
        },
        {
          substance: "Calcium Citrate",
          amount: "500",
          measure: "mg",
          id: uuidv4()
        },
        {
          substance: "D3",
          amount: "16000",
          measure: "IU",
          id: uuidv4()
        },
        {
          substance: "Magnesium",
          amount: "80",
          measure: "mg",
          id: uuidv4()
        },
        {
          substance: "Zinc",
          amount: "10",
          measure: "mg",
          id: uuidv4()
        },
        {
          substance: "Multi-vitamin",
          amount: "1",
          measure: "Tablets",
          id: uuidv4()
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ...
  return (
  ...
      <Portal>
        <HomeStarterModal
          homeModalVisible={homeModalVisible}
          homeData={homeData}
          hideHomeModal={hideHomeModal}
        />
      </Portal>
  ...
      <ScrollView
        horizontal={true}
        style={{
          padding: 6,
          paddingHorizontal: 10
        }}
      >
        <Starters
          item={itemData["Vits"]}
        />
        <Starters
          item={itemData["Vits2"]}
        />
      </ScrollView>
  ...
)
```